# Add xml file to Eclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I have a file `model.xml` i want to add to my eclipse plugin to read at runtime.

I tried adding it to the `manifest.mf` `binary build` and `source build` and adding it to the `build.properties` `bin.includes` but when I look in the `bin` folder there are only `.class` files.

Surely plugins can contain resources and not just `.class` files right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just list the file in the `bin.includes` in the `build.properties` - you should be able to do that in plugin.xml/MANIFEST.MF/build.properties editor.

For example in one of my plugins the `build.properties` is:

```
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .,\
               OSGI-INF/,\
               plugin.xml,\
               fragment.e4xmi
source.. = src/
```

Which includes a `plugin.xml` and a `fragment.e4xmi` file.

Note: These are not copied to the `bin` directory in your project. When you test your plugin they will be accessed directly in the project. When you build/export your plug-in they will be included in the plugin jar.

You use the `FileLocator` API to access these files - that understands where to look.

For example, to access the `fragment.e4xmi` shown above:

```java
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass());
// or some other way to get the current bundle

URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("fragment.e4xmi"));
```

Comment: Thanks, I had tried something similar but wrongfully assumed it wasn't working when in fact the conversion from url to path was my problem.

Comment: If you want to just read the file you can just call `openStream` on the URL, use `FileLocator.toFileURL` on the URL if you must have a separate file (this may copy the file to a temporary location)